# How to install ruby compass on Mac OS 10.8.2

Tags: ruby, macos, compass-sass

I start `gem update` and it runs something like this :

```
Marios-MacBook-Pro:~ MarioVMtz$ gem update --system
Updating RubyGems
Updating rubygems-update
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.
```

I installed `xcode rvm` what else do I need to install `ruby compass` on Mac OS 10.8.2?

Comment: Did you install any rubies with rvm? If so, did you set one of them to be the default?

Answer (score 2):

Run the command using sudo? **sudo** gem update --system should sort your immediate problem.

Comment: Sudo would solve the problem if he wants to install Compass under the system ruby, but since he mentioned rvm, it seems like maybe he wants to install Compas under a ruby managed by rvm?

Comment: I said **immediate** problem.